# Can't instantiate AbstractSet Class

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

Ok I've been searching for this problem for a while.
I keep getting an error that I can't instantiate `abstractSet`. 
It keeps asking for a generic. I add the generic but still no dice.

```
import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.Set;
public class UnorderedTree{

private Object root;
private Set subtrees; //Switched to AbstractSet
private int size;

public UnorderedTree(Object root){
     this(root);
     subtrees = new AbstractSet(); //ERROR HERE WITH <Object>
     size=1;
   }
}
```

Any pointers would help

Comment: The sole purpose of an abstract class is that it's to be extended. Either extend it or use a concrete, built-in subclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As its name suggested, **AbstractSet** is abstract, you can not instantiate it. as its javadoc  said:

> This class provides a skeletal implementation of the Set interface to minimize the effort required to implement this interface.

You should use some concrete set like **[HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)**.

Answer (score 3):

AbstractSet is an "abstract" base class, which *cannot* be instantiated. It has a protected constructor which is overridden by the classes that extend this abstract class.

Please look at the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html) for more help.

Direct known subclasses of this class are: ConcurrentSkipListSet, CopyOnWriteArraySet, EnumSet, HashSet, TreeSet - You are probably interested in one of these.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

AbstractSet is an abstract class. You can't instantiate abstract classes, because they (generally) don't contain a complete implementation of the type they're defining. It has nothing to do with generics.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize `abstract` classes.

From `Java 6` API this is the definition of the `AbstractSet` class.

```
public abstract class AbstractSet<E>
extends AbstractCollection<E>
implements Set<E>
```

For more information please refer [Java API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html).

Your can overcome this compilation error by using:

```
private Set<YourObjType> subtrees = new HashSet<YourObjType>();
```

Comment: I assume you meant 'can't instantiate'?